# How do I submit a value from a dynamic dropdown to another database?

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML form with a dropdown select for choosing a name which is dynamically populated from a MySQL database using PHP. How would I submit that value or chosen name with the form?

Here is my dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" name="nameselect" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Name</option>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):?>
        <option value="<?php echo ($row1["fullname"]);?>"><?php echo ($row1["fullname"]);?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //first check if it's selected

    if(isset($_POST['save']) && isset($_POST['nameselect'])){

    $name=$_POST['nameselect'];

    //using mysqli prepared statement

    $result=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(?, ? )") ; //query
    if ($result){ //if query
    $result->bind_param('ss', $name, $anyothervalue ); //bind the parameters
    $result->execute();   //execute the query
    }

   if($result->affected_rows >0){ //if data is inserted
   echo "Added Successfully!!!"; //success message
   }
   else{ 
   echo "error"; //error message
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's a beautiful looking piece of code :-) I'll give it a go and let you know. Many thanks and greatly appreciated.